# An error occurred while processing your request. Request ID: 0HLEALBF2I2PS:00000007

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

While running a ASP .Net project in Visual Studio I am getting error like this.
This is a sample project. I have written the proper Action methods which are same like the project I have already done. Still, I am getting errors like this.

I am getting an output like this:
[image]

Comment: but what is your question ?

Comment: have your read the message posted ? it is said that the project is not build in debug mode and that is the reason that you don't see the error message. Have you try to build the project in debug mode ?

Comment: @schlebe My question was, usually when this happens? When output comes like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### I looked for the solution and I found this.

Add the Views for respective action methods. This will solve the problem.

---

If not then please check for name of views which should be with same name as action methods. And should be within the folder /Views/[ControllerName]/

---

Answer (score 1):

This is the ASP.NET Core default error view, indicating something in *your code* failed. Have a look at setting the environment to Development, to enable the default [Developer Exception Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Next to that: set a breakpoint in your action, call the page again and see what's wrong.

Comment: Yes when I added the environment to Development, It gives detailed exception Thanks. It helped me.